# Segmentation fault generic double linked list

Tags: c++, data-structures, segmentation-fault

I am trying to implement a generic double linked list. The member function which adds node as the head is giving segmentation fault(core dumped). I think the error lies somewhere in else block in add_..head() function in "d_list.h".
I can't figure out where the error is?

> Question: How to find segmentation fault in code?
>
> d_list.h

```
    #ifndef NODE_H
    #define NODE_H
    
    
    #include<iostream>
    #include "node.h"
    template<class T>
    class d_list{
        private:
          int l_size;
          Node<T>* head;
          Node<T>* tail;
    
        public:
           //default constructor
           d_list(){
              head=nullptr;
              tail=nullptr;
           }
           
           Node<T>* gethead(){return head;}
           Node<T>* gettail(){return tail;}
           
           int get_list_size(){
              return this->l_size;
           }
    
           void add_node_as_head(T data){
              Node<T>* current_node= new Node<T>(data);
              if(this->head=nullptr){
                 
                 this->head=current_node;
                 this->tail=current_node;
                 current_node->next=nullptr;
                 current_node->previous=nullptr;
                 this->l_size=l_size+1;
                 
           }else if(this->head!=nullptr){
               
               this->head->previous=current_node;
               
               current_node->previous=nullptr;
               this->head=current_node;
               this->l_size=l_size+1;
               
           }
       }
  void removefromfront(){
     Node<T>* temp = this->head;
     this->head=this->head->next;
    
     this->l_size= l_size-1;
  }
    };
    
    #endif
```

> node.h

```
template<class T>
class Node{
  private:
     
     T data;
  public:
     Node<T>* previous;
     Node<T>* next;
     Node()=default;
     Node(T m_data){
        data=m_data;
        previous=nullptr;
        next=nullptr;
     };
     

};
```

> main.cpp

```
    #include<iostream>
#include "d_list.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){

   d_list<int> d1;

   cout<<d1.gethead()<<"Head Initially";
   cout<<"\n";
   d1.add_node_as_head(5);
   cout<<d1.gethead()<<"Head after adding 1st element\n";
   cout<<d1.gettail()<<"Tail after adding 1st element\n";

   d1.add_node_as_head(6);
   cout<<d1.gethead()<<"Head after adding 2nd element\n";
   cout<<d1.gettail()<<"Tail after adding 2nd element\n";
   
   d1.add_node_as_tail(7);
   cout<<d1.gethead()<<"Head after adding element as Tail\n";
   cout<<d1.gettail()<<"Tail after adding element as Tail\n";

   cout<<d1.get_list_size()<<"Size after adding three elements\n";
   d1.removefromfront();
   cout<<d1.gethead()<<"Head After Removing from front\n";
   cout<<d1.gettail()<<"Tail After Removing from front \n";

   cout<<d1.get_list_size()<<"\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried gdb can't fix it!

```
Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000041598e in d_list<int>::add_node_as_head (this=0x7bfe30, data=5) at d_list.h:40
40      nullptr){
(gdb)
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Have you tried going through it with a debugger?

Comment: @BigTemp Yes,  edited my question

Answer (score 1):

In add_node_as_head function you are using **Assignment operator** (this->head = nullptr).

Instead you should use **Equal to Operator** (this->head == nullptr).

Comment: I was missing the '==' operator. I have added a new function called removefromfront() but it's returning 0 as i print head after removing head. I have also updated the d_list.h.

Comment: Code updated please look for the function removefront() in d_list.h